# Document Library for PDF's for View/Print only

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, 2016

I've made a document library for some regulatory documents that we would like users to be able to view and print but not download. 
I'm aware that users can still use print screen or retype documents, the purpose of this library is to make it more convenient to print the document, without the ability to download it to the desktop.
I've got all access groups set with "view-only" permissions.
As far as I can tell PDF's do not have server-side file handlers, so the View-Only permission still allows users to download.
I've heard that SP 2013 made some headway on this issue without resorting to IRM. Is there a way to handle this in 2016/online?